Including an Arduino painlessmesh library within another library and calling functions - No matching functions
I am starting to write a library that needs to incorporate the painlessmesh library as its core function, essentially, a wrapper around it. I started putting it together but quickly hit a snag wrapping the painlessmesh lib. I know I am missing something in the declaration, just cant figure out what.
Any help would be great moving this on.
I have the following code:
myLib.h
#ifndef myLib_h
#define myLib_h

#include "Arduino.h"

   struct libNode{
   String deviceName;
   String nodeName;
   String Parameters;
    };

class myLib
{
  public:
    myLib(libNode node);
    //myLib(int node);
    void beginMesh(String meshPrefix, String meshPassword, int meshPort);
    void updateMesh();
  private:
    EscapeNode _node;
    void receivedCallback(uint32_t from, String &msg);
  //int _node;
};

#endif

and in my myLib.cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "myLib.h"
#include "painlessMesh.h"
    
    Scheduler userScheduler;  // to control your personal task
    painlessMesh mesh;

// Constructor
myLib::myLib(EscapeNode thisNode)
{
    // Intialise the variable
    _node = thisNode; //{"testDevice", "TestNode", "Parameter JSON String"};
    
    // Start Up The Node
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //beginMesh();

}

void myLib::beginMesh(String MESH_PREFIX, String MESH_PASSWORD, int MESH_PORT) {
Serial.println('beginMesh');
Serial.println(MESH_PREFIX);
    Serial.println(MESH_PASSWORD);
    Serial.println(MESH_PORT);

      //mesh.setDebugMsgTypes( ERROR | MESH_STATUS | CONNECTION | SYNC | COMMUNICATION | GENERAL | MSG_TYPES | REMOTE ); // all types on
  mesh.setDebugMsgTypes(ERROR | STARTUP);  // set before init() so that you can see startup messages

  mesh.init(MESH_PREFIX, MESH_PASSWORD, &userScheduler, MESH_PORT);
  mesh.onReceive (&myLib::receivedCallback);
  //mesh.onNewConnection(&newConnectionCallback);
  //mesh.onChangedConnections(&changedConnectionCallback);
  //mesh.onNodeTimeAdjusted(&nodeTimeAdjustedCallback);

  //userScheduler.addTask(taskSendMessage);
  //taskSendMessage.enable();
    
}

// Needed for painless library
void receivedCallback(uint32_t from, String &msg) {
  Serial.printf("startHere: Received from %u msg=%s\n", from, msg.c_str());
}

I have a very simple test program:
#include <myLib.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  libNode node;
  node.deviceName = "TestDevice";
  node.nodeName = "TestNode";
  node.Parameters = "{XXXXX}";

  myLib thisNode = myLib(node);

#define MESH_PREFIX "xxxx"
#define MESH_PASSWORD "xxxx"
#define MESH_PORT 5555

  thisNode.beginMesh(MESH_PREFIX , MESH_PASSWORD , 5555);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

I get this error message when I try and compile:
d:\Users\richa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\myLib\myLib.cpp: In member function 'void myLib::beginMesh(String, String, int)':
d:\Users\richa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\myLib\myLib.cpp:39:51: error: no matching function for call to 'painlessmesh::wifi::Mesh::onReceive(void (myLib::)(uint32_t, String&))'
mesh.onReceive (&myLib::receivedCallback);
^
In file included from d:\Users\richa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Painless_Mesh\src/painlessMeshSTA.h:6,
from d:\Users\richa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Painless_Mesh\src/painlessMesh.h:20,
from d:\Users\richa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\myLib\myLib.cpp:9:
d:\Users\richa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Painless_Mesh\src/painlessmesh/mesh.hpp:227:8: note: candidate: 'void painlessmesh::Mesh::onReceive(painlessmesh::receivedCallback_t) [with T = painlessmesh::Connection; painlessmesh::receivedCallback_t = std::function<void(unsigned int, String&)>]'
void onReceive(receivedCallback_t onReceive) {
^~~~~~~~~
d:\Users\richa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Painless_Mesh\src/painlessmesh/mesh.hpp:227:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void (myLib::)(uint32_t, String&)' {aka 'void (myLib::*)(unsigned int, String&)'} to 'painlessmesh::receivedCallback_t' {aka 'std::function<void(unsigned int, String&)>'}
exit status 1
Compilation error: exit status 1

mesh.onReceive() is expecting a static callback function, you can't have some method of your Class pretend to be a static function with &myLib::receivedCallback. Change mesh.onReceive(&myLib::receivedCallback); to mesh.onReceive(receivedCallback); and comment out void receivedCallback(uint32_t from, String &msg); in myLib.h. BTW, your code has other problems. EscapeNode is nowhere defined, and Serial.println('beginMesh'); should be Serial.println("beginMesh");.

Overall, this wrapper doesn't add any value or make things simpler. The PainlessMesh library already provided the level of abstractions for you to use, if you want to have better organization of your code. you could wrap all the configuration and setup in a function like "configMess()" instead of having another layer of abstraction with a C++ class... Einstein once said, "Thing should be simple, but not simpler".

Many thanks for the help. It all pointed me in the right direction and I have finally managed to get my library off the ground for development.
It turns out that my there is probably more wrong with my original code than right, Multiple issues (as pointed out above) and its more a lesson of what not to do, however, it was a start and you have to start somewhere.

One of the main issue was the position of the call back functions, they have to be declared before the constructor. With all the other pointers above I managed to get my code compiled.
In answer to @hcheung, I appreciate your point, however this code will be included in lots of different devices, If I edit the underlying communications protocol then I want to edit once and just recompile each device rather than needing to make multiple edits. Thanks for the advice, much appreciate.
